# Debug dynamically loaded assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic, assemblies

I am debugging an assembly which I loaded dynamically with [Assembly.Load(Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329934%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), but I am facing some problems.

First of all, I can't move the yellow arrow in Visual Studio 2010 to step into other lines of code, and also I am getiing exceptions ("Cannot find the method on the object instance.") when trying to do a quick watch on objects from a third party library (controls from Infragistics for example.)

```
Dim data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName)
Assembly.Load(data)
```

When using [Assembly.Load(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329935%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), everything works fine, and there are no problems.

```
Assembly.Load(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name))
```

Any idea why the behaviour is that much different? Anyway to fix this?

I tried loading the debugging symbols for my assembly with Assembly.Load(byte[]. byte[]), but I still get exceptions when trying to debug objects from third party libraries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The debug symbols for your assembly are not being loaded into the application domain.  When you use the string variety, .NET automatically looks for a .PDB alongside the filename you specify.

To load an assembly *and* its symbols from byte arrays, use [`Assembly.Load(byte[], byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twt16z2x.aspx), like so:

```
Dim data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName)
Dim pdbData = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(pdbFile.FullName)
Assembly.Load(data, pdbData)
```

Comment: I tried this, and the symbols got loaded, but I have still problems with classes/objects from dependencies of this assembly.

Comment: You will have to manually load dependencies as well.  Subscribing to the [AssemblyResolve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012/loading-assemblies-and-its-dependencies/22026#22026) event may be helpful in your case.

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately, when I tried it, it did not fix my problem. Do you know if this is one of the things that are currently broken in netcore?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass it an array of bytes there's no way to know what file it comes from (or if it even comes from a file) so it can't locate the PDB file with the source code line information.

You can fix this by saving the `byte[]` as a file and making sure there's a PDB for it with the same file name.