# .Net Core debug dynamic loaded dll

Tags: debugging, .net-core

We are writing a console app using .Net Core 2.0. In the app, we load several DLLs from a sub-folder dynamically (by using "Assembly.LoadFromFile()"). And when I set a break-point in which DLL was loaded dynamically, the break-point cannot be hit.
But I am pretty sure the code was called, because I printed out some log information to the console, and the log was there.
So i would like to know why my break-point is not hit? And I have put the corresponding "PDB" files in the sub-folder. And when I opened the "Debug->Windows->Modules" view, i can see the "PDB" files were loaded successfully. So what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing helps from here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074596/debugging-code-from-dynamically-loaded-assembly-in-net-core-2-0

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I read that one before I asked this question. I tried the method mentioned in that post. But nothing help for my case.

Comment: Do you have the source code files? Whether your .pdb files match your source code files? Are you using the correct PDB files (as they differ for .Net Core and .NET Framework)?

Comment: HI Ivan, thanks for you reply, but i think i have add the correct pdb file into the right place. And I also take a look at the "Debug->Modules" window, it said the pdb files are loaded successfully. So, have to try some other way.

Comment: Does the source code match that pdb?